# What is the limit of this sequence created using Pascal's triangle?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients

Let use the [Pascal Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle) to create a sequence. We sum from the first term on the left to the term in the middle [image]

and then we take the inverse root times two. We get then that the terms are

> \begin{eqnarray}
> &&a_0 := 2 \\
> &&a_1 = 2 \frac{1}{1^{1/1}} = 2\\
> &&a_2 = 2 \frac{1}{(2+1)^{1/2}} = 1.154700\dots\\
> &&a_3 = 2 \frac{1}{(3+1)^{1/3}} = 1.25992\dots\\
> &&a_4 = 2 \frac{1}{(6+4+1)^{1/4}} = 1.098200\dots\\
> &&a_5 = 2 \frac{1}{(10+5+1)^{1/5}} = 1.14869\dots\\
> &&a_6 = 2 \frac{1}{(20+15+6+1)^{1/6}} = 1.0727\dots\\
> &&a_7 = 2 \frac{1}{(35+21+7+1)^{1/7}} = 1.10408\dots\\
> \end{eqnarray}

The first line of the triangle creates the $a_0$ the second creates the $a_1$ and so on. Then I have my **conjecture:**

> This sequence converges to 1

But I couldn't prove it or disprove it. What I did was tried to relate to the Binomial expansion: Let $0\leq x \leq 1$ so we have that

$$(1+x)^2 = 1 + 2x^2 + x^4 \geq x^2 + 2x^2 = 3x^2$$

So we have that

$$\frac{x}{x+1} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

And I tried to translate this to some limit using this $x$. There is a way to solve this problem like this? This series converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the elements in "half a row" of Pascal's triangle is either $2^{n-1}$ (if we are talking about the $n$-th row with $n$ being odd) or $2^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{n/2}$ if $n$ is even, due to $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$. 
The central binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$ behaves in the following way
$$ \binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}} $$
hence you are essentially asking about
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} 2\cdot\frac{1}{(2^{n-1}+E(n))^{1/n}} $$
that is clearly $1$.

Comment: @HazemOrabi: oh, many thanks, now fixed.

Comment: What is $E(n)$?

Comment: @RafaelWagner: an error term that is $o(2^{n-1})$.