# How does one show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1\choose k}^x\right)^{1/(2n+1)}={2\over x}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Sort of generalisation of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167860/what-is-the-limit-of-this-sequence-created-using-pascals-triangle)

How does one show that

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n+1\choose k}^x\right)^{1/(2n+1)}={2\over x}\tag1$$
>   $x\ge1$

Answer (score 0):

$${2n+1\choose n}^x<\sum_k{2n+1\choose k}^x<n{2n+1\choose n}^x$$
so your limit is between $\left[{2n+1\choose n}^{1/(2n+1)}\right]^x$ and $n^{1/(2n+1)}\left[{2n+1\choose n}^{1/(2n+1)}\right]^x$

Comment: Could you please let me know how to show $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left[{2n+1\choose n}^{1/(2n+1)}\right]^x=\frac{2}{x}$.

Comment: I think $log( \left[{2n+1\choose n}^{1/(2n+1)}\right]^x)$ goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.